# JqueryUi slide effect with duration won't stop when click on other link

Tags: jquery-ui, hide, show

While I'm on PAGE 1, I click on PAGE2 link, it will slide to the right with duration 2seconds, While it is sliding, I CANNOT click PAGE1 link. How do I click on page1 or stop the slide while it's sliding?
Help me please

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.link2page1').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#page2').hide(
                    function(){
                        $('#page1').show();
                    }
                );
        });

        $('.link2page2').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#page1').hide('slide',{direction:'right'},2000,
                function(){
                    $('#page2').show();
                }
                );

            });
    });
```

Please check out my code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hamdlink/mG26f/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will help you.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.link2page1').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#page2').hide(
                        function () {
                            $('#page1').stop();
                            $('#page1').css("left","0px");
                            $('#page1').show();
                        }
                    );
        });

        $('.link2page2').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#page1').hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 10000,
                    function () {
                        $('#page2').show();
                    }
                    );
        });
    });
```